# How can I import both the module and a specific part of it in one line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import

I need these two imports in my test:

```
import "./Wizard.js";
import { Wizard } from "./Wizard.js";
```

However, ESLint keeps deleting one of them on fix because it breaks the `import/no-duplicates`-rule. How can I write both imports in one line?

If I leave out the first my tests break and if I leave out the second it doesn't compile.

Comment: `import * as wizard from "./Wizard.js";` then `const { Wizard } = wizard;`

Comment: @code Do I get the side effects if I name the import? I thought I wouldn't?

Comment: You always get the side effects no matter what names you import.

Comment: Typically, one uses a "bare import" like the first one for the side effects, since you don't get any references from it. If running the second import only breaks something, your module is doing something wrong. Or right, depending on your perspective :).

Comment: I tried @code s idea and I'm getting the error `TS2749: 'Wizard' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Wizard'?`

Comment: How about `import w, { Wizard } from "./Wizard.js";`? You could create an empty default export.

Comment: @code `TS1192: Module '"Wizard"' has no default export.`

Comment: Yes, so you need to add a default export, e.g. `export default {};` (exports nothing). Or if you want specific code inside your file to be executed that isn't in an export, move it into the default export (`export default function() { /*your code here*/ };`).